# Fast way to read specific data in Java

Tags: java, io

I have this code:

```
System.setIn(new FileInputStream( System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/one.in"));
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

for (i = 0; i < ...; i++) {
      String line = reader.readLine();
      String firstLocation = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' '));
      String mid = line.substring(line.indexOf(' '), line.lastIndexOf(' ')).trim();
      String secondLocation = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
      ....
}
```

and I read many lines of the form:

```
A --875-> B
A <-854-- B
A --713-> B
A <-908-- B
A --925-> B
A <-894-- B
A --239-> B
A <-30-- B
A --802-> B
```

Is there a fastest way to read and process this lines? I also tried reading all the lines at one and that split using the end-of-line character, but it works even slower.

Comment: I'd probably use `line.split(" ")`, but the question is if you're doing anything else in that loop that may cause the slowness.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way I know is using the [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html). Then your code would look like this:

```
System.setIn(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") "/src/one.in"));
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

while (reader.ready()) {
    final StringTokenizer tk = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine()," ");
    String first = tk.nextToken();
    String second = tk.nextToken();
    String third = tk.nextToken();
    ...
}
```

I would not check here if there are enough token available, beause you know th structure of you input String, which also saves time. As you can see [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/splitting_tokenisation_performance.shtml#.VETWCq0gjmE) that StringTokenizer is faster than using `Pattern` or `split(...)` method.

Comment: From the docs: "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."

Comment: That's true, but he asked for performance not for compatibility :-)

Comment: But +1 for finding proof of it being faster in a similar case.

Comment: I think the OP should try this, but note that `" "` should be faster than `\s+` so the evidence doesn't exactly match. Performance could have also changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] parts = line.split(" ");
String firstLocation = parts[0];
String mid = parts[1];
String secondLocation = parts[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you design your method and save it as a library (or even as a template in an IDE!)
For example, if you want to read integer from System.in, you can use this function

```
static int readInt(BufferedInputStream b) throws IOException {
    String s = "";
    int x = b.read();
    while (x < 48 || x > 57) {
        x = b.read();
    }
    while (x >= 48 && x <= 57) {
        s = s + (char) x;
        x = b.read();
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```

This method will fetch you the next available Integer in an input.
This method ignores any non-numeric character.

For example, if your input be like :

```
"    123    !!!@@b"
```

the output will be solely

```
123
```

The important part is that this method does the role of nextInt() in Scanner but way fast than the former.